# Поочередное появление блоков js, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Нужно реализовать поочередное появление блоков начиная с нижнего, и так по кругу. Написал код на jQuery, работает, но после переключения вкладки браузера идет рассинхронизация - появляются в произвольном порядке. Почему так? Может есть другое решение.
Строго не судите, пока учусь.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.olive').fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
  $('.blue').delay(500).fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
  $('.red').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box red">1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue">2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box olive">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может вам нужно использовать вместо setInterval  - setTimeout? Или так и нужно, что бы код каждые 4 секунды срабатывал? Может быть такое, что когда вы возвращаетесь, вся анимация, которая должна была отобразиться - отображается "за раз"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поочередное появление блоков

```js
$(function() {
  var box = $(".box").get(),
    len = box.length,
    indx = 0,
    opacity = 0,
    duration = 4000 / len;
  box.reverse();
  (function fn() {
    $(box[indx]).delay((len - indx) * duration / 3).fadeTo(duration, opacity, fn);
    indx = ++indx % len;
    if (!indx) opacity = +!opacity
  })()
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 8px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: только непонятно, почему в моем варианте рассинхронизация. Спасибо за решение

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#минимальная-задержка-таймера

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так только переключать окна нужно не чаще чем  сет интервал там еще подключен дополнительный скрипт

```js
var slideshow = setInterval(function() {
    if (Visibility.hidden()) {
        $('.olive').delay().fadeIn();
        $('.blue').delay().fadeIn();
        $('.red').delay().fadeIn();
        return false;
    };
    $('.olive').fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
    $('.blue').delay(500).fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
    $('.red').delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 1).fadeToggle(1000);
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/visibility.js/1.2.4/visibility.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box red">1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box blue">2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box olive">3</div>
</div>
```